# Is this series bounded?

Tags: convergence-divergence

$$
\frac{2^n3^n}{n!}
$$

I know the series is not monotonoic. I believe the series is bounded below at when n goes to infinity the series will go to 0, but never hit it. I just don't know if the series is bounded above.

Comment: This is a **sequence**. A series is a **sum** of (countably) infinitely many numbers. I have had a couple hundred students who ran afoul in an exam problem because they forgot the distinction. Hence the nitpick. Also a friendly piece of advice: making the distinction clear in your mind avoids misapplication of theorems, and unnecessary deductions from your exam scores!

Comment: The sequence *is* monotonic for n >6.

Answer (score 1):

$a_n = \dfrac{2^n3^n}{n!} = \dfrac{6^n}{n!}$

Then, $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{6}{n+1}=0$.

Therefore, the series converges, and is therefore bounded.

Comment: Much better if you say that since the series $\sum a_n$ is convergent (because of the Ratio Test), then $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$ and hence the sequence $(a_n)$ is bounded.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's bounded. To see this, notice that it's monotonic decreasing for $n>6$.